# (Mono For) Android EditText Show Current Value?

Tags: android, android-edittext, xamarin.android

I have got a PreferenceActivity Screen, where I save some Values.
(But I think it doesn't mind, if it would be just a normal Activity)..

Anyway at the moment it looks like this:

[image]

There are 4 EditText Controls. It saves the values fine, but I would like,
that the stored/saved current value will be showed on this edittext, without needing to 
select one of these EditTexts first, to be able to see it..

Maybe somehow on the second line of the EditText, **Protokoll**, and then on the darker **grey Protokoll** place, the current value, for example: ***HTTP***

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the XML for your layout and `TextView`s? You should be able to just create a reference to the second `TextView` and change the `Text` property.

Comment: I provided the XML, actually there aren't any TextView's, its the summary property under each title..

Comment: Why don't you try changing the summary property to the current setting for that particular config?